# youtube iframe api not loading in ionic app but on reloading the page, it works

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, youtube

I am using youtube iframe api in ionic sidemenu app and when the template is loaded from the side menu it does not show the video player but once I press the reload button of chrome browser or press `ctrl+f5` I can see the player.

***Here is my code:***

```js
     var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                  player = new YT.Player('player', {
                  height: '390',
                  width: '640',
                  videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                  events: {
                          'onReady': initialize
                                }
                    });
            }
   
function initialize(){
                  console.log("init");
                                    }
```

```html
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
                 <br/><br/>
                <div id="player"></div>
                <div id="slider-6"></div><br/><br/>
                <div id="button"></div>
                <div id="id"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: are you getting the "init" logged on your first load?

Comment: no nothing happens the first time

Comment: Actually I have written this js code in external js file. So the first time the controller gets loaded but this external js doesn't get loaded

Comment: I got the thing work using the plugin on https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed.